# Dynamic custom field issues

Tags: custom-fields

This works (all tags output):

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="section_homepage" disable={global:param_disable_all_with_cats}}
{{channel_short_name}_top_banner}
{channel_short_name}
{section_homepage_top_banner}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This doesn't work:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="section_homepage" disable={global:param_disable_all_with_cats}}
{{channel_short_name}_top_banner}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This outputs `{{channel_short_name}_top_banner}` as a string, rather than parsed.

it's as though I need to include BOTH:

```
{channel_short_name}
{section_homepage_top_banner}
```

BEFORE the dynamic tag parses....

```
{{channel_short_name}_top_banner}
```

I'm using Structure 3.3.14.5 and EE 2.81.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using {channel_short_name} for the tag anyways? Is your channel actually dynamic in your entries tag?